# How to connect xib's view to another viewcontroller's view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, view, autolayout

I have a question about view. 
How to let mainVC xib's view connect menuVC's view? 
Why I set this code and not work to show background color?

> self.cvBottom = menuView

Or I miss something to set?
Or I just only use auto layout in programing? 
thanks.

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cvBottom: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {

        self.setupBottomCollectionView()
    }

    func setupBottomCollectionView() {
        
        let menuView = MenuController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()).collectionView
        self.cvBottom = menuView //Not work here. What's wrong?
    }
    
}


class MenuController: UICollectionViewController {
    
    fileprivate let cellId = "MenuCell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .red
        collectionView.register(MenuCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

}

extension FavoriteMenuController {
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MenuCell
        cell.lbTitle.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `Not work here.` mean ? Can you elaborate on what is the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

First, in general, it's a bad idea to "replace" an `@IBOutlet`.

Second, you are "extracting" the `view` from `MenuController` but you are not loading any of its ***code*** ... you need to add it as a **child** view controller.

So, in `MainVC`, replace your `cvBottom` collection view with a plain `UIView`. We'll then add the view from `MenuVC` as a subview:

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cvBottom: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.setupView()
    }
    
    func setupView() {
        
        self.setupBottomCollectionView()
    }
    
    func setupBottomCollectionView() {
        
//      let menuView = MenuController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()).collectionView
//      self.cvBottom = menuView //Not work here. What's wrong?

        // load menuView CONTROLLER
        let menuView = MenuController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        
        // add it as a child view controller
        addChild(menuView)
        
        // add menuView's view as a subview of cvBottom
        self.cvBottom.addSubview(menuView.view)
        
        // set its frame and resizing mask
        menuView.view.frame = self.cvBottom.bounds
        menuView.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        // finish the "add child" process
        menuView.didMove(toParent: self)

    }
    
}
```